# Change style of individual path labels?

Tags: labels, tikz-styles, paths, layers

I am working on creating a path diagram using Tikzedt.

The problem I'm running into is that the path labels on these lines that are very close to each other are overlapping with the other lines, rendering them illegible. (see image below).

I feel like there ought to be a way to expand the white background around each of the labels that my current code is producing.

The solutions I've seen thus far on this forum put code in the header that change the styles of all nodes that are path labels, or all nodes. I do *not* want that, because this is a subset of a much more complex diagram with many other paths that I want to stay the same.

Maybe I need to create a new style in the header and use that style only for the path labels? I'm not really sure, and would appreciate any input.

I feel like there's a simple solution, but haven't yet found anything that gets at this sort of issue.

I'm not very familiar with the intricacies of tikz code (if that wasn't already obvious), and I'm currently building off of a template a colleague of mine sent me.

Please forgive any code that is redundant or nonsensical, because I'm not totally sure what I'm doing.

[image]

Here is the code I used to produce this image:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,backgrounds,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=10mm,fill=white,inner xsep=5pt,inner ysep=8pt] 
\tikzstyle{line} = [-latex'] 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm,font=\bfseries\boldmath\large,line width=1.25pt]

%Place time point 1 Observed variables
\node [block] (Y010A) {$Y_{01r}$};

%Time point 2 observed variables
\node [block, below=10 cm of Y010A] (Y020A) {$Y_{02r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y020A] (Y120A)  {$Y_{12r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y120A] (Y220A)  {$Y_{22r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y220A] (Y320A)  {$Y_{32r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y320A] (Y420A)  {$Y_{42r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y420A] (Y520A)  {$Y_{52r}$};

%Place reference trait factors and paths
\node[draw, circle, right=4 cm of Y010A, minimum size=1.25cm](TrA) {$T_{r}$};
\path [line] (TrA.140) edge (Y010A.30);

\path [line] (TrA.210) edge node {} (Y020A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.220) edge node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.1]{$\lambda_{8}$} (Y120A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.230) edge node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.12]{$\lambda_{9}$} (Y220A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.240) edge node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.14]{$\lambda_{10}$} (Y320A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.250) edge node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.16]{$\lambda_{11}$} (Y420A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.260) edge node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.18]{$\lambda_{12}$} (Y520A.30);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is exactly what you were expecting, but here is a piece of code that may be convenient :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,backgrounds,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, minimum width=12mm, minimum height=10mm,fill=white,inner xsep=5pt,inner ysep=8pt]
\tikzstyle{line} = [-latex']
\tikzstyle{path_node_wide} = [fill=white, text width=11mm]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm,font=\bfseries\boldmath\large,line width=1.25pt]

%Place time point 1 Observed variables
\node [block] (Y010A) {$Y_{01r}$};

%Time point 2 observed variables
\node [block, below=10 cm of Y010A] (Y020A) {$Y_{02r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y020A] (Y120A)  {$Y_{12r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y120A] (Y220A)  {$Y_{22r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y220A] (Y320A)  {$Y_{32r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y320A] (Y420A)  {$Y_{42r}$};
\node [block, below=0.5cm of Y420A] (Y520A)  {$Y_{52r}$};

%Place reference trait factors and paths
\node[draw, circle, right=4 cm of Y010A, minimum size=1.25cm](TrA) {$T_{r}$};
\path [line] (TrA.140) edge (Y010A.30);

\path [line, path_node_wide] (TrA.210) edge node {} (Y020A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.210) edge node {} (Y020A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.220) edge node[path_node_wide, pos=0.2]{$\lambda_{8}$} (Y120A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.230) edge node[path_node_wide,pos=0.22]{$\lambda_{9}$} (Y220A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.240) edge node[path_node_wide,pos=0.24]{$\lambda_{10}$} (Y320A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.250) edge node[path_node_wide,pos=0.26]{$\lambda_{11}$} (Y420A.30);
\path [line] (TrA.260) edge node[path_node_wide,pos=0.28]{$\lambda_{12}$} (Y520A.30);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I defined a new style (`path_node_wide`) that I only apply on the desired nodes. Concerning the white background of your labels, I explicitly give `text width` so that the label is the expected size (although I think a better way may exists...). I also move a little your labels, as I found them more readable at that place).

You may find here the result :

[image]

I hope it may help a little.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the help. I figured it was something along those lines, but didn't know how to define a new style of node.